# Is it possible to block certain APIs in a proxy created by AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, aws-api-gateway

I've followed the tutorial [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-http.html) to create an API with HTTP Proxy Integration using AWS API Gateway.

Suppose my backend server supports `GET /foo`, `GET /bar`, and `GET /ooo/xxx` APIs. Is it possible to modify the API Gateway so that only `GET /foo`, and `GET /bar` are exposed, and no one can access `GET /ooo/xxx` through AWS API gateway?

[image]

Comment: *"In the API just created, the API's proxy resource path of `{proxy+}` becomes the placeholder of any of the backend endpoints under `http://petstore-demo-endpoint.execute-api.com/`."*  There is no need to use `{proxy+}` in the resource when making a proxy API -- this is just an example of how you can capture everything and forward it, if that's what you actually want (which it sounds like you don't).  Can you just model the API with the specific desired resources specified explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it using the Resource Policy of the your API. Go to Resource Policy and on the bottom, there are example buttons to generate policy to blacklist certain IP range. Click on that and add your source IPs and ARN where necessary.

[image]